# Error When migrating after using 2 foreign keys of same table

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

in my model I have to have 2 foreign keys that are of same model. i tried related name so makemigrations works fine. but when i'm trying to migrate, it throws an error and says

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "service_requested_by_id" cannot be cast automatically to type uuid
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING service_requested_by_id::uuid".
```

my model

```
class Schedule(BaseModel):
    project = models.ForeignKey("projects.Project",null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey("logistics.Vehicle",null=True,blank=True)
    driver = models.ForeignKey("staffs.Staff",related_name='driver',blank=True,null=True)
    service_requested_by = models.ForeignKey("staffs.Staff",related_name='service_requested_by',blank=True,null=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    starting_km = models.DecimalField(null=True,blank=True,default=0,decimal_places=0, max_digits=15,validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0'))])
    completed_km = models.DecimalField(null=True,blank=True,default=0,decimal_places=0, max_digits=15,validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0'))])
    travelled_km = models.DecimalField(null=True,blank=True,default=0,decimal_places=0, max_digits=15)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'schedule'
        verbose_name = _('schedule')
        verbose_name_plural = _('schedules')
        ordering = ('vehicle',)  

    class Admin:
        list_display = ('vehicle',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.vehicle:
            return self.vehicle.name
        else:
           return str(self.project)
```

It was working all fine till i added the service_requested_by field. any hint what i am possibly doing wrong? do i need to post anything else beside this code?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the error occurred because I changed the type of column `service_requested_by` from textinput to foreign key. It messed the whole things up. What I needed to do was to create another column with a different name and leave the old column as it was, without changing its type. Now everything works fine.